# Does LDS Modals by default restrict tabbing behind it?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, html, slds

I am wanting to not tab behind a modal when that modal is opened. Reading the [documentation for modals](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/modals/) provided by salesforce, it seems that they take care of it. But when I am testing it I get mixed results. Does anyone know if this is a expected feature to restrict tabbing to outside of a modal or does the functionality not exist?

HTML:

```
<section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-modal="true" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open slds-modal_large">
  <div class="slds-modal__container">
    <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-modal__close slds-button_icon-inverse">
      <svg class="slds-button__icon slds-button__icon_large" aria-hidden="true">
        <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#close"></use>
      </svg>
      <span class="slds-assistive-text">Cancel and close</span>
    </button>
    <div class="slds-modal__header">
      <h1 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-modal__title slds-hyphenate">Modal header</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1">
      <p>Sit nulla est ex deserunt exercitation anim occaecat. Nostrud ullamco deserunt aute id consequat veniam incididunt duis in sint irure nisi. Mollit officia cillum Lorem ullamco minim nostrud elit officia tempor esse quis. Cillum sunt ad dolore quis
        aute consequat ipsum magna exercitation reprehenderit magna. Tempor cupidatat consequat elit dolor adipisicing.</p>
      <p>Dolor eiusmod sunt ex incididunt cillum quis nostrud velit duis sit officia. Lorem aliqua enim laboris do dolor eiusmod officia. Mollit incididunt nisi consectetur esse laborum eiusmod pariatur proident. Eiusmod et adipisicing culpa deserunt nostrud
        ad veniam nulla aute est. Labore esse esse cupidatat amet velit id elit consequat minim ullamco mollit enim excepteur ea.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-modal__footer">
      <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral" aria-label="Cancel and close">Cancel</button>
      <button class="slds-button slds-button_brand">Save</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open" role="presentation"></div>
```

Comment: Have you tried using the new modal LWC base class to implement your modal?